# Inheriting Copy and Paste function on extended screens

Tags: acumatica

We are trying to extend the concept of Copy and Paste function on screen to our custom screen so when users copy on Sales Order screen it should also copy the extended/custom screen fields so we can paste it back to new document.

How do we inherit copy and paste functionality to add those additional custom fields? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think any editable field on the page is automatically copied using the page copy/paste function unless being excluded via PXCaopyPasteHiddenFields attribute. Might be possible to include fields not on the page or disabled, but I have no experience with this. Try to look into "PXCopyPasteAction" to see what calls are made there for copy/paste

Comment: I have gone through the source code, did not come across any method related to PXCopyPasteAction to override.

Comment: Are you trying to copy and paste to the same screen? I assume you have added your custom fields to the page and the fields are enabled? if so they should work out of the box when copy/paste to same screen.

Comment: I have added custom fields to Soorder table. The fields are captured through custom page and not part of SO page. I am trying include those fields also part of copy & paste

Comment: if they are not on the page then they will not be copied. Not sure what is available in the copy/paste portion of the framework that would allow this. This is a good question and hope someone could answer if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Copy-Paste feature only works with input controls and grid columns defined on Aspx page. To paste custom field values to a new sales order, you should create input controls for each custom field and verify they stay enabled for the Copy-Paste feature to work (values from read-only controls and cells are always excluded from the copy function).

Since the copy function does not check if control is visible on the screen (only is control is disabled), to extend the copy-paste function with custom fields you can add hidden control for every your custom field by setting `Visible` property to ***False*** in Layout Editor:
[image]

Comment: Hello Ruslan, thanks for the feedback, however we won't be able to put all custom fields on the main screen since we have 100's of custom fields accepting production related data, which actually led us to create these new screens. 
We will explore the "Copy Order" from action menu and see if that helps us to get the job done or write our own "copy action".

Comment: @MuralidharanRamakrishnan, actually the **Copy Order** button from **Actions** menu should copy values of all custom fields, that you added to the SOOrder DAC, **without any modifications**. Could you please verify that?

Comment: Would be nice if the sales order action "Copy Order" will not include fields defined in PXCopyPasteHiddenFields.